# Play YouTube Videos in Android app using Exoplayer with Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, exoplayer

I want to play a YouTube video in my android app and I need to add new videos everyday. So I would like to access the YouTube video link from firebase database everyday. I would like to use Exoplayer. Is that possible? I am new to android development and a beginner. Please help me.

Comment: Firebase can store youtube links, exoplayer can play video links. Show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: It's definitely possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dona you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can play youtube video in exoplayer for this you have to extract dash-url from video link.
https://github.com/nhCoder/YouTubeExtractor
this link will help you to extract dash url working perfectly fine for me.